# Angular 2 - waiting for a service to have the infos - return promise when variable is set

Tags: angular, service, promise

the main **app.component** is requesting data from a web service

then it sets a variable in a service called **coreService** which gets injected everywhere to access these data

the problem is that the **others component get loaded before app.component** gets the infos, so I get tons of undefined issues

- I dont fetch data from coreService otherwise the webservice is called multiple times (tried to use a condition and pipe() but it does not work)
- I tried using AfterViewInit, yet it works intermitently

app.component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.catalogService.getCampaign().then((data: any) =>
    {
        this.coreService.campaign=data;
    });
}
```

products.component: (the component loaded in the router-outlet)

```
constructor(private coreService:CoreService)
{}

ngAfterViewInit()
{
    Promise.resolve(null).then(() => {   // to avoid value changed error b@#!t from angular
        if(this.coreService.campaign)
        {
                        ... // we should be here                
        }
        else
        {
            console.dir(this.coreService);
            throw "campaign not loaded yet";
        }
    });
}
```

I want the two components to be synced, I mean, the **products** component has to wait for the **coreService** to have its data

this undefined in chained then:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppResolver implements Resolve<boolean> {

  constructor(private catalogService: CatalogService, private coreService:CoreService) { }

  public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<boolean> 
  {
    return this.catalogService.getCampaign(CoreService.CAMPAIGN_IDENTIFIER,null).then((data: any) => 
    {
        this.coreService.campaign=data;
        return true;
    })
    .then(function(result) : Promise<boolean>
    {
        // below this is undefined and throws an error
        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        return this.catalogService.getCampaign(CoreService.CAMPAIGN_IDENTIFIER,null).then((data: any) => {
            this.coreService.campaign=data;
            return true;
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo should fetch data in a [Resolver](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data).

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyDataResolverService implements Resolve<boolean> {

  constructor(private catalogService: CatalogService, private coreService:CoreService) { }

  public resolve(): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.catalogService.getCampaign().then((data: any) => {
        this.coreService.campaign=data;
        return true;
    });
  }
}
```

then use the resolver in your route configuration

```
...
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    resolve: {
      dataResolved: MyDataResolverService
    }
  }
....
```

Comment: the route is to be added in app routing module ? I dont have any entry for this

Comment: I got an error with route(), I dont understand why it's not working....
I updated my question with an image

Comment: error with route() is my mistake "export class MyDataResolverService implements Resolve<ture>" should have been "export class MyDataResolverService implements Resolve<boolean>". i updated my post. the route i added is just an example to show how it is done, it is not exact implementation suitable for your exact use case since  i don't know how you handle routing. you should add resolver to an appropriate place in your route configuration such as where you route to products.component. if you add your route config i can help.

Comment: ok it builds, but what if I have to chain many web services request before doing the resolve, and they depend from one another?

Comment: the you should chain promises in resolve() as explained in here https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Comment: i am glad that it helps. please do not forget to up vote and accept the answer.

Comment: I tried to add a second then, but this is not defined inside of it, I guess I should use bind but I suspect I do something wrong, I updated my question

Comment: I return this from one promise to another, I found I also could do ()=>this.something.. but I dont like the syntax

Comment: you have to use fat arrow syntax. otherwise you will get undefined error for "this". there is a section named "What’s this?" in this article https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/ please take a look at it.